# "moment.isMoment is not a function" when executing Sequelize command from Electron Renderer

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite, electron, sequelize.js

I have an electron app that is using Sequelize to interact with my SQLite database. Interestingly, the same command works perfectly fine when executed from Electron main, but gives an error when executed from Electron renderer.

Here is the error:

```
data-types.js:527 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: moment.isMoment is not a function
at DATE3._stringify (data-types.js:527:17)
at DATE3.stringify (data-types.js:27:19)
at DATE3.bindParam (data-types.js:38:35)
at SQLiteQueryGenerator.format (query-generator.js:1091:29)
at SQLiteQueryGenerator.insertQuery (query-generator.js:186:30)
at SQLiteQueryInterface.insert (query-interface.js:784:37)
at User.save (model.js:4226:73)
```

Here's how my project is set up:

models/user.ts

```
export class User extends Model<
  InferAttributes<User>,
  InferCreationAttributes<User>
> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare displayName: string;
  declare tagLine: string;
  declare server: string;
  declare createdAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  declare updatedAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
}
```

models/index.ts

```
init();

async function init() {
  // Get app path from ipcMain listener when using renderer.
  // Get app path directly when executed from main
  let path =
    (await electron.ipcRenderer?.invoke("read-user-data")) ||
    electron.app.getPath("userData");

  const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: "sqlite",
    storage: path + "/databases/database.sqlite",
  });


  User.init(
    {
      // Model attributes are defined here
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      displayName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: "users_display_name_tag_line_server_index",
      },
      tagLine: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: "users_display_name_tag_line_server_index",
      },
      server: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: "users_display_name_tag_line_server_index",
      },
      createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
      updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "User",
      underscored: true,
    }
  );

  sequelize
    .sync({ force: true })
    .then((response) => {
      // This works
      let user = User.create({
        displayName: "test2",
        tagLine: "test2",
        server: "test2",
      });
    })
    .catch((e: Error) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
}

export { User };
```

Renderer worker.ts

```
import { User } from "../../models";

// Timeout is temporary workaround to allow for sequelize database setup to finish
setTimeout(() => {
  // Does not work. Gives moment.isMoment error
  let user = User.create({
    displayName: "test",
    tagLine: "test",
    server: "test",
  });
}, 5000);
```

Main index.ts

```
workerWin = new BrowserWindow({
  //show: false,
  webPreferences: {
    preload: join(__dirname, "../preload/index.cjs"),
    nodeIntegration: true,
    contextIsolation: false,
    webSecurity: false,
    backgroundThrottling: false,
  },
});
```

...

```
ipcMain.handle("read-user-data", (event) => {
  return app.getPath("userData");
});
```

...

```
setTimeout(() => {
  // This works
  let user = User.create({
    displayName: "test",
    tagLine: "test",
    server: "test",
  });
}, 6000);
```

I've tried several things to try to resolve this.

First off, I tried deleting node_modules then reinstalling the modules; did not help.

I did find somewhere saying that sequelize v7 (currently alpha) was moving away from using moment, so I tried installing that, but I was still getting the exact same error.

Despite my project not needing moment, I tried installing the moment module in case that had any effect. Same error.

I know that I could transfer my processes to main rather than using it in my renderer, but I would like to avoid that if possible. It is a worker file rather than an actual rendering window, and there are lots of processes that will be interacting with the database in this worker window.

Answer (score 0):

Actually not find any exact solution but i have a temparory solution.

this issue coming due to date field in your table that you trying to insert / update.

if you convert that field into string. and also false the timestamps in sequilize then you will see this isMoment error is no longer. I hope this will help you  ..

```
 public static initialize(sequelize: Sequelize) {
    this.init({
        date: DataTypes.STRING,
        "shop_id": DataTypes.BIGINT,
        "type": DataTypes.ENUM("Regular","Exceptional"),
        "status": DataTypes.ENUM("Active","Inactive"),
        "supply_rate": DataTypes.DOUBLE(8,2),
        "retail_rate": DataTypes.DOUBLE(8,2),
        "other_rate": DataTypes.DOUBLE(8,2),
        "wholesale_rate":DataTypes.JSON,
        "created_at": {
            "type": 'TIMESTAMP',
            "defaultValue": Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
        },
        "updated_at": {
            "type": 'TIMESTAMP',
            "defaultValue": Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
        }
    }, {
            sequelize: sequelize,
            timestamps: false
    })
}
```